# How do I access the opt out target ads option on Android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to access the current status of the Interest-based Ads, just need to know if it's currently active or not. That option can be found on the Settings of the Android Market App or on the Google Settings App. Can anyone direct me on how to get that property?

Answer (score 0):

It's under the `Pricing and Distribution` tab of EACH app you have in the console, down at the bottom. You need to set it for every app.

[image]